# Android SDK Eclipse AndroidManifest.xml not created

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest

I've downloaded the **ADT Kit** from the **Android Developer Website**, but if I try to create a new Project (`New-> Android Application Project`), the **Manifest** file is not created. In the console window, I get the message:

```
'[2013-12-13 15:50:08 - package name] AndroidManifest.xml file missing!'
```

How can I solve the problem?

I already tried to clean the Project and run again, but the xml file isn't created. I tried also to uninstall (delete) the SDK and download it again, but there is the same mistake.

Comment: I had such problem some weeks ago and as far as i remember correctly, i had to update SDK or ADT and everything works fine. But you also can try click on "Fix project" in properties of your project.

Comment: is AndroidManifest.xml the only file missing ? what about project.properties ? and the gen folder

Comment: did you try to restart eclipse? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
First, I Updated my SDK, but it wasnt the problem. The problem was the character 'ö' in the project / package name. Eclipse didn't create the Manifest because of him.
It's a German App...

Comment: funny, have a try to change workspace character encoding to UTF-8 if it isn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, right click the project or edited resource and select “Refresh”.
If you edit outside of Eclipse a lot, you can enable auto-refresh by going to Window->Preferences menu, then in the Preferences dialog box, select General > Workspace.
Check the “Refresh automatically” box.

and even in the eclipse in the top menu bar you can find `search-->check the automatically build`

Comment: The refreshing did not helped, I think there is a bigger problem in eclipse.